# Deselecting the currently drawn feature?

Tags: javascript, select, openlayers-3

I have a JS code using OL3. what I wanna do is to draw lines and do the snapping and splitting. I have done it all so far but there is one minor thing. I wish to highlight the point that should be snapped to or the lines be broken at. But, as this process is done as soon as a new line is added, the currently added line remains highlighted. I wanna deselect it before highlighting the node.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var addFeatureEventListener = vector2.getSource().on('addfeature', addFeatureFunction);

function addFeatureFunction(e){
    map.removeInteraction(lineStringdraw);
    vector2.getSource().unByKey(addFeatureEventListener);
    //console.info("the listener is deactivated now....");
    var currentFeture = vector2.getSource().getFeatures()[vector2.getSource().getFeatures().length-1];
    if(!undone){


        var featureGeom = currentFeture.getGeometry();
        console.info(featureGeom.getCoordinates().toString())
        var endNodeCoordinates = featureGeom.getLastCoordinate();
        snapIndex= endNodeCoordinates.length-1;
        selectedFeatures.clear();
        map.renderSync();
        checkSnapping(nodes, endNodeCoordinates, currentFeture);
        if(snap){
            var featureCoordinates = featureGeom.getCoordinates();
            featureCoordinates[featureCoordinates.length-1]= snapToNode;
            featureGeom.setCoordinates(featureCoordinates);
            currentFeture.setGeometry(featureGeom);
            currentFeture.changed();
            snap=false;
        }
        var isPartOf = addSegment(featureID-1);
        currentFeture.getProperties().partOf[isPartOf[0]]=isPartOf[1];
        drawing = false;
        drawing_feature = null;
    }
    if (!sorting){
        var newLines =  checkIntersection(currentFeture);   
    }
    map.addInteraction(lineStringdraw);
    addFeatureEventListener = vector2.getSource().on('addfeature',    addFeatureFunction)
}
```

I had to remove the draw interaction when a feature is added to the layer (addFeatureEventListener ). But this removes the feature. Is there a way so that I can deselect the feature.

**Tip:** to highlight a node or a line, I have a selectFeatures, an object of ol.interaction.Select(), that I add the desirable feature to and render the map.